# How to retrieve access tokens from different social networks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

In my Rails application I need to connect to different social networks in order to fetch public contents. Even if they are public it's often needed an access token. I wonder whether it is possible to use the oauth2 gem just to retrieve/update access tokens which I than will use to make API calls.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You will have to get the tokens manually from the social sites, as you need to register your application.